# Is there a new feature to load lazy routing module in Angular 15?

Tags: angular

In my Angular 12 application I use the code below to preload all the routes (including all lazy module routes). Even though the `configLoader` is a private property, my code works well. So far I haven't heard of any alternative way to do this.

```
(<any>router).***configLoader***.load(injector, route).subscribe({
        next: (moduleConf: any) => {
          const children: any = [];
          children.push(...moduleConf.routes.map((childRoute: any) => childRoute));
          routes.push({ path: currentPath, children });

          children.map((childRoute: any) => {
            if (childRoute.children && childRoute.children.length > 0) {
              childRoute.children.map((x: any) => {
                preload(currentPath, x);
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

After I upgraded my project to Angular 15, I can't compile it anymore since there is no more `configLoader` (it looks like the corresponding property was removed). I've been googling for a few days but haven't found any solutions yet. Can any of you give me some advice on how to rewrite the code above for Angular 15? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi there. Can you include the full error message in the post?

Comment: The error message is 'configLoader is undefined'!!

Comment: Hi. Why aren't you using `preloadingstrategy: PreloadAllModules` in the `RouterModule.forRoot` call? It's really as simple as that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled into this issue and found a solution that seems to work fine.

Simply change the first line:

```
(<any>router).configLoader.load(injector, route).subscribe({
```

with this one:

```
(<any>router).navigationTransitions.configLoader.loadChildren(injector, route).subscribe({
```

I don't know what's going on under the hood, I just looked for a function with the same signature and a similar name. So there may be some unexpected behavior in some scenarios.

It's working fine in my case though.

Comment: Hey Rodro, thanks for sharing this solution, I understand it's not the open method in Angular but anyway, it helped me to settle this problem. Thanks again!